# Running Hadoop in Local Mode for Production

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata, distributed-computing

I have been working on Hadoop for quite some time now, we all know that we use local mode for building our scripts/jobs and to test them locally. 
But If we have a scenario where as some of our customers have small data sets and some have larger datasets and we do not want to write two code peices of the business logics-one for local running mode and one for distributed mode running, then how to go about it.

One approach for production deployment would be to give the Local Mode Running of the Hadoop Jobs/Pig/MR jobs to the customers having small data set and give a distributed mode of setup for customers having larger data sets.

My Question is:
Giving Local Mode Hadoop Setup on production (because the data size is not very big), is it a good idea?!

Should pseudo-distributed mode be the choice for small data sets in production, I would need some thoughts on limitations faced on each of the approach (Local Mode and pseudo-distributed mode) and if there are any risks involved in deploying the same for productions. Kindly help if anyone has encountered such design challenges.

Kindly advice more..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ship some of our product editions in pseudo-distributed mode and even in local mode in case of extremely slow disks and lack of CPU resources. These configurations are typically installed on virtual machines so what we recommend to customers is scheduled VM backup. This takes care of recovery to some extent.

The important thing is to inform customers of inherent tradeoffs in performance and reliability and at the same time to encourage them to think of current configuration as the right architecture for scalability going forward, should they be satisfied with functionality and overall results on a smaller scale.

We have customers running in pseudo-distributed mode with 1 unscheduled downtime incident over for a 2 year period - it was a power outage at the hardware level. There was some data loss involved due to ungraceful shutdown but it was limited in scope.

One thing we've done for these installations is to schedule an automated major compaction in HBase that is triggered by cron during off-peak hours on a daily basis.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your approach. The way we look at it is that we are responsible for hardware cost and is a part of a overall solution price to the customer. Hence, we do not want to invest on unnecessary hardware if not required , at the same time, invest on it if there are risks involved with running things on local mode. So slow hardware and low resources are not a problem for us, its the elimination of risk which we are working towards. Kindly advice with respect to small data for any limitations (apart from scalibility) in local mode setups , like open bugs in local mode, etc.,..!!! :)

Comment: I'm not able to provide a list of open bugs. Our stack might be different from yours. We had to tweak default settings to make sure our stack works for our use case, eg avoiding oom in scans etc.

Comment: The use case might be different, but thats sounds Interesting,. Can you please elaborate more like what kind of settings you had checked before allowing the local mode of hadoop to be run on production. That is very important point...

Comment: Sorry, it would take a lot of time to collect all the changes we've made to properties files, both for server-side and client-side, .e.g HBase client. You'd have to look at your particular use case. I just wanted to share the fact that we use pseudo-distributed mode in production for small-scale installations. If my experience, limited as is, was valuable to you, pls acknowledge and upvote.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge on this topic.!!